# ActionBarSherlock - styling the action bar issue

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using actionBar sherlock and having a problem with styling the action bar. Only on one device (samsung galaxy nexus) after loading the starting activity action bar loses it's style(becomes white, instead of my background image). Here some code:

actionbar_style:

@style/MyActionBarTabStyle

```
<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/head</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/head</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/blue_for_menu</item>
</style>

<style name="textStyleActionBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and the manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:name="BBB"
             android:theme="@style/actionBarStyle"
        >
```

initActionBar method:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.head);
        bg.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(bg);

        BitmapDrawable bgSplit = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.head);
        bgSplit.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        getSupportActionBar().setSplitBackgroundDrawable(bgSplit);

        // sm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sliding_menu_selector_for_icecreamsandwich);
        // sm.setSelectorDrawable(R.drawable.sliding_menu_selector_for_icecreamsandwich);
        sm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sliding_menu_selector_for_icecreamsandwich);
    }

}

private void actionBarInit() {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);}
```

Please, help me, someone!!!